# What privileges should I give my MySQL database user for my Flask application?

Tags: python, mysql, security, database-connection, flask-sqlalchemy

Is there a standard set of privileges that should be given to the user used to access a Flask SQLAlchemy database. For example with

```
application.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://app@127.0.0.1/test'
db = flask.ext.sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy(application)
```

what privileges should `app` be given?

[image]

Comment: Depends, what action are avaialbe to your user?

Comment: Is there a minimal set to get things working on an exception database (assume no additions or modifications are made from the Flask application)?

Comment: Than just check SELECT